# Memcached get taking too long to respond

Tags: php, performance, caching, memcached, file-get-contents

I've a strange problem with memcached. I have searched [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/495963/slow-memcached-average-10ms-memcached-get), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921627/memcached-slow-gets-high-cpu-usage), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866551/why-does-php-memcache-have-a-very-slow-response), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841493/memcached-slow-queries) and [few other places](https://www.google.co.th/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=memcached%20slow%20gets) about my query. So I've got two pages `index.php` and `index2.php` (please don't mind file naming).

`index.php` contains the following code:

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('test.txt');
    echo "done";
```

And `index2.php`contains the following code:

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_new($filename, $memcache){
    $time = filemtime($filename);
    $hash = md5($filename.$time);
    $content = $memcache->get($hash);
    if($content){
        return $content;
    }
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $memcache->set($hash, $content, 10000);
    return $content;
}
$memcache = new Memcached;
$memcache->addServer('localhost', 11211);
file_get_contents_new('test.txt', $memcache);
echo "done";
```

There's one more file `test.txt` which has html source from a random site which is around `58967` characters which is around `57.6kb`.

Now when I tried to profile `index.php`, I got the following profiling results (I'm using xdebug for profiling and phpstorm to view data):

[image: file_get_contents shows 0% time]

Now when I try to profile `index2.php`, I get the following snapshot:
[image: shows $memcached->get() takes a lot of time]

We can see clearly that `$memcache->get()` is taking very long time which doesn't make much sense as I'm running Memcached on my local machine.

Then I thought maybe it's just some error and tried apache's benchmarking tool `ab`. The exact command I executed was `ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://localhost/index.php`
Which was pretty fast and results were:

```
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.20
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /index.php
Document Length:        4 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.555 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      2030000 bytes
HTML transferred:       40000 bytes
Requests per second:    18025.33 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       5.548 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.055 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3573.38 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       1
Processing:     1    5   0.8      5      19
Waiting:        1    5   0.7      5      19
Total:          2    5   0.7      5      19

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      5
  66%      6
  75%      6
  80%      6
  90%      6
  95%      7
  98%      7
  99%      8
 100%     19 (longest request)
```

Then I did the following test `ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://localhost/index2.php`

```
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.20
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /index2.php
Document Length:        4 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   9.044 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      2030000 bytes
HTML transferred:       40000 bytes
Requests per second:    1105.72 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       90.439 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.904 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          219.20 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       1
Processing:     6   79  71.1     76    5090
Waiting:        6   79  71.1     76    5090
Total:          7   79  71.1     76    5090

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     76
  66%     78
  75%     79
  80%     81
  90%     85
  95%     89
  98%     93
  99%    107
 100%   5090 (longest request)
```

Which is very slow and is weird. Why is reading from memory slower than reading from secondary storage. Or did they implement some caching on `file_get_contents`

The computer I'm working is pretty strong and has following configuration:

- MANJARO OS (Linux Kernel 4.1.26-1)
- 16GB Primary Memory
- 256GB SSD
- Intel core i7 processor

Edit: As @ShiraNai7 commented, I tried to change my server URL to 127.0.0.1 and below are results from apache benchmarking tool

```
Server Software:        Apache/2.4.20
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /index2.php
Document Length:        4 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   11.611 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      2030000 bytes
HTML transferred:       40000 bytes
Requests per second:    861.25 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       116.111 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.161 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          170.74 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    3  47.0      0    1009
Processing:     6  113  67.6    105     633
Waiting:        6  111  67.1    103     633
Total:          6  116  82.5    106    1197

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    106
  66%    135
  75%    153
  80%    167
  90%    204
  95%    235
  98%    286
  99%    334
 100%   1197 (longest request)
```

Which is an improvement, but not a lot. And I can't see why would dns lookup take so long, since it's on `/etc/hosts` and it's sitting on my local machine.

Edit: I also tried to see if there's any APC going on, which I couldn't find I did find `Opcache` module. Is that why file_get_contents faster?

I've [hosted](http://jsbin.com/cayisohopa) a jsbin where you can see how my phpinfo looks like in my machine.

Comment: Try changing *localhost* to *127.0.0.1* to make sure the DNS lookup isn't the culprit here.

Comment: Hi @ShiraNai7 , I tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 which was a significant improvement but still it's too slow, since comments have character limit, I've edited my question and mentioned new results, can you have a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: Just my 2c, ditch memcached for Redis...got better performance and less headache..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out the mystery behind this question. First clue was `file_get_contents` was very fast. Even if I'm using SSD, it shouldn't be that fast. So I dug around whole night and found some interesting information.

It's because file_get_contents is also returning the cached information. PHP itself doesn't include caching, but linux system has built in file cache which makes it extremely fast to access data repetitively.

Reference: [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)